# Causes of intermitant Arg_ArgumentException on in Production deployment?

Tags: silverlight, exception, silverlight-5.0

We have just recently deployed a Trusted, In-Browser, Silverlight 5 application to our Production webserver.  We are getting fairly frequent ArgumentExceptions captured by the App.xaml.cs UnhandledException handler.  So far we have been unable to determine the source of the exception.

We are not seeing the exception when running under the debugger (I have that explicitly enabled the exception for capture under Debug->Exceptions....).  Some users see this error very frequently, while others never see the error.  It doesn't seem to be a fatal error as the users can just click the OK button from the ErrorWindow that we display and everything functions normally.

To stop annoying the users, I have added a handler for ArgumentException types and just mark it as handled and continue on.  However, I am still logging the errors and would really like to determine the actual source so that I can fix the problem.  Just ignoring the exception doesn't seem like a long term solution.

The Stack trace is below and is the same for all ArgumentExceptions.

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot better and determine the cause of this exception?

Thanks,

Tim

```
Unhandled Exception: [Arg_ArgumentException] 
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.10411.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_ArgumentException :    
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr) 
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, Double d) 
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj) 
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object value) 
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Object newValue) 
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation) 
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty dp) 
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget() 
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired() 
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.PerformTargetLoaded() 
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TargetLoaded(Object o, RoutedEventArgs e) 
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args) 
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex
```

Comment: That looks like a problem in a binding expression.

Comment: Maybe some clients use an older silverlight runtime. Try to update those clients and see if the problem is gone.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a runtime version issue.  I am seeing the same error with both SL5 and SL5 sp1.  What is causing me problems is that fact that it is only seen by some users and I don't see the problem in a debugging session.

Comment: I have the exact same problem - the cause is not at all clear and we cannot reliably reproduce - fun! Have there been any further news on this question?

Comment: Anyone found out something about this? We are facing the same issue lately.